# jQuery Ajax setTimeout JSON

Tags: jquery, json, settimeout

I am using the jQuery AJAX to call JSON service. I am then spitting out the data to .html. I would like 2 things to happen. 
1.  I want a refresh button to refresh the data, not the whole page.
2. I want a setTimeout or setInterval (which ever works best) to update the data every 5 minutes or so. But refresh the page.
How would I wrap the AJAX in a setTimeout or setInterval or refresh the data using a button and a timer every 5 minutes or so. I know this should be simple but I have not been able to get it to work. Thanks in advance.

Below is my code.

```
    $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "/myservice.asmx/WebMethod",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
      var myval = msg.d;
      // $('#jsonstring').html(myval);
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(myval);
      $('#Data1').html(obj.DataOne);
      $('#Data2').html(obj.DataTwo);

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.statusText);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

Comment: Nevermind I figured out the auto reload and the button click sorry for the extraneous question

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did. I also found out from this post that the interval or timeout will race against the data load and the load. so I had to write it like this.

```
  function myFunction() {
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myservice.asmx/WebMethod",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
           var myval = msg.d;
           // $('#jsonstring').html(myval);
           var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(myval);
           $('#Data1').html(obj.DataOne);
           $('#Data2').html(obj.DataTwo);

           //TO SET THE TIMEOUT FOR DATA TO LOAD

           setTimeout(function(){
              yourFunction();
           }, 300000);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           alert(xhr.statusText);
           alert(xhr.responseText);
           alert(xhr.status);
           alert(thrownError);
        }
     });
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
     //Load on Doc Ready
     myFunction();

     //Reload on button click
     $('#myBtn').click(function(){
        myFunction();
     });

     //TO SET THE TIMEOUT FOR DATA TO LOAD - Need both in the success and here.

     setTimeout(function(){

        myFunction();

     }, 2000);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function rData(){
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/myservice.asmx/WebMethod",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
          var myval = msg.d;
          // $('#jsonstring').html(myval);
          var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(myval);
          $('#Data1').html(obj.DataOne);
          $('#Data2').html(obj.DataTwo);

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
}

setInterval(rData,300000);

<input type='submit' value='refresh' onclick='rData();return false;'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ajax call is working, you can just put it in a function and reference that in a timer / interval.

```
function Refresh() {
    /* your ajax code */
}

setInterval(Refresh, 300000); // five minutes, in milliseconds

$("#MyButton").click(Refresh);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only run the Refresh() function once, after the first 5 minutes are up?

Comment: @JakeFeasel No, `setInterval` repeats it indefinitely, as opposed to `setTimeout`, which only does it once. So there's no need to reset the timeout like you have in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function refreshContent() { 
    $.ajax.....
}   

function refreshContentTimer() { 
    refreshContent();
    setTimeout(refreshContentTimer, 300000); // 5 min
}

$(function () {

    setTimeout(refreshContentTimer, 300000); 
    $("#refreshButton").click(refreshContent);

}
```