# How can I make a continually updating query in MVC 3?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking for a simple way to make a piece of text, which happens to be a number, on my view update in near-real-time.

I have a piece of text in my view that looks like this:

```
<% if (ViewData["TotalRecords"] != null)
   { %>
<%= ViewData["TotalRecords"].ToString() + 
                    " records available to search."%>
<% } %><br />
```

I want `ViewData["TotalRecords"]` to be a constantly updating value, every 60 seconds or so.

The query underneath is:

```
public static string GetTotalRecords()
        {
            DataContext dc = new DataContext();
            return dc.Records.Count().ToString("#,##0");
        }
```

How can I make this into some kind of Ajax-enabled dynamic piece of text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move that part to separate action

```
public ActionResult TotalRecords()
{
   var totalRecords = GetTotalRecords();
   return PartialView(totalRecords);
}
```

In parent view, initially render that action with

```
<div id="totalRecords">
     @Html.RenderAction("TotalRecords")`
</div>
```

And script with [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to reload TotalRecords action every 60 seconds

```
<script>

$(function(){
     setInterval("reloadTotalRecords", 60 * 1000);
});

function reloadTotalRecords()
{
    $('#totalRecords').load('@Url.Action("TotalRecords")');
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's going to have to be some JavaScript in there somewhere. A `setTimeout` could be used to call an ajax method that returns the number, which then is used to update the content in the browser.

You could use jQuery to target the specific element. There are some examples on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187604/jquery-ajax-settimeout-json).

Answer (score -1):

I believe this should solve your question:
[jQuery Ajax setTimeout JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187604/jquery-ajax-settimeout-json)

Use the JavaScript setTimeout function to call an Ajax function every 60 seconds.

Something like:

```
function updateContent() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'url',
cache:false,
      success: function(data) {
    $('#item-id').html(data.NewValue);
    },
      dataType: 'json'
    });
    }

    $(function () {
        setTimeout(updateContent, 60000); 
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I would jump into [SignalR](http://signalr.net/). Sounds interesting.

Comment: I've been using SignalR, and I love it, but I think it might be overkill to use it instead of a simple, timed AJAX request